# Update view in Django WITHOUT using generic classes

Tags: django, django-views

I think I don't understand something fundamental here, but every single tutorial on the topic proposes a solution using either a function or a generic class, and both of them work for me, but I can't figure out how to deal with the issue using just View. So to illustrate where I am at, I am building a very simple blog and want to update data on a single post based on it's id. So what I have is:

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update') 
]
```

update_post.html

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ isolated_post.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

and finally views.py

```
class PostUpdateView(View):

    form_class = PostForm
    initial = {'key': 'value'}
    template_name = "blog/update_post.html"

    def get(self, request, pk):
        isolated_post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
        form = self.form_class(instance=isolated_post)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, pk, form):
        updated_post = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=form)

        if updated_post.is_valid():
            updated_post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/post/" + f'{pk}/')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'updated_post': updated_post})
```

I've tried a lot of things, this time it says that form has not been passed to the post function. but the most I can achieve is the empty form, which throws out an error after I press "update". I think I just do not get the logic of "post" well enough, or how to populate the form with the one i use get function on.

Answer (score 0):

## Your view

```
class PostUpdateView(View):`

    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = "blog/update_post.html"

    def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.post_instance = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=kwargs['post_id'])
        return super().setup(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post = self.post_instance
        form = self.form_class(instance=post)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post = self.post_instance
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_post = form.save(commit=False)
            new_post.save()
            return redirect('your dynamic url', post.id)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried the code, but it gives me keyerror for post_id and i am not sure why...

Comment: insted of using pk in urlpatterns, use <int:post_id> or change post_id to pk in view                   (and form.as_p in your template)